# x86 Convert ASCII Character to Digit

Tags: assembly, x86, ascii, masm, irvine32

I am having a doozy of a time with a homework assignment and would love some guidance.  The assignment requires you to convert an ASCII character string in any base and output into any base.  The program hangs when I call the AsciiToDigit procedure (nested within the ReadInteger procedure) and I can't figure out why.  The debugger is no help in that it doesn't do anything but hang when it gets to that portion of the program.

I am fairly certain I need to convert the character to a digit first to do this correctly but maybe I'm missing something.  Thanks for any help anyone can provide.

```
    TITLE MASM Template                     (main.asm)

; Description:
; 
; Revision date:

INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
.data
basePrompt BYTE "What base (2-16 or 0 to quit): ",0
numPrompt BYTE "Number please: ",0
invalid BYTE "Invalid base, please try again.",0
base2 BYTE "Base 2: ",0
base8 BYTE "Base 8: ",0
base10 BYTE "Base 10: ",0
base16 BYTE "Base 16: ",0
base DWORD 0


.code
main PROC
        call Clrscr
    State0:                             ; initial state to accept base number
        mov edx, OFFSET basePrompt
        call ReadBase
        cmp al, '0'                     ; check if 0 entered    
        je ProgEnd                      ; jump to ProgEnd if 0 entered
        mov base, ebx
        mov edx, OFFSET numPrompt
        call WriteString
        call ReadInteger

        mov ebx, 2
        mov edx, OFFSET base2
        call WriteString
        call WriteInteger
        mov ebx, 8
        mov edx, OFFSET base8
        call WriteString
        call WriteInteger
        mov ebx, 10
        mov edx, OFFSET base10
        call WriteString        
        call WriteInteger
        mov ebx, 16
        mov edx, OFFSET base16
        call WriteString
        call WriteInteger


        call Crlf
        jmp State0                      ; jump back to beginning of program

    ProgEnd:                            ; jump point to end of programt

    exit
main ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------------
ReadInteger PROC
;
; ReadInteger is passed one argument in bl representing the base of the number to be input. 
; Receives: bl register
; Returns:  EAX
;-----------------------------------------------------
nextChar:
     call ReadChar          ; Get the next keypress
     call WriteChar         ; repeat keypress
     call AsciiToDigit      
     shl   ebx,1            ; shift to make room for new bit
     or    ebx,eax          ; set the bit to eax
     cmp al, 13             ; check for enter key
     jne   nextChar
     ret
ReadInteger ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------------
WriteInteger PROC
;
; Will display a value in a specified base
; Receives: EAX register (integer), bl (base)
; Returns:  nothing
;-----------------------------------------------------

     mov   ecx, 0         ;count the digits
nextDigit:
     mov   edx, 0         ;prepare unsigned for divide
     div   ebx
     push  edx            ;remainder will be in dl
     inc   ecx            ;count it!
     cmp   eax,0          ;done when eax becomes 0
     jne   nextDigit

;now the digits are on the stack
;pop them off and convert to ASCII for output
outDigit: 
     pop   eax              ;digits come off left to right
     add    eax, '30'       ;add 0011 to front to get ASCII
     call  WriteChar
     loop  outDigit

     call Crlf
     ret



    ret
WriteInteger ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------------
ReadBase PROC
;
; Prompts the user for input and stores input into EAX.
; Receives: EDX register
; Returns:  EAX
;-----------------------------------------------------
    Call WriteString

    xor ebx, ebx                ; clear ebx
        call ReadChar
        call WriteChar
        cmp al, '0'
        je Done
        cmp al, 13              ; look for return carriage, jump to end
        je Done
        mov ebx, eax
        shl ebx, 1              ; shift ebx left one
        call ReadChar
        call WriteChar
        or ebx, eax

    Done:
        call Crlf
    ret
ReadBase ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------------
AsciiToDigit PROC
;
; This procedure receives the ASCII code of a digit and returns the numerical digit value.
; Receives: EAX register
; Returns:  EAX
;-----------------------------------------------------
    cmp eax, 61h
    jb Upper
    sub eax,61h
    jmp done

    Upper:
        cmp eax, 41h
        jb Digit
        sub eax, 41h
        jmp done

    Digit:
        sub eax,30h

    done:
        ret
AsciiToDigit ENDP

;-----------------------------------------------------
DigitToAscii PROC
;
; This procedure receives digit and returns Ascii value
; Receives: EAX register
; Returns:  EAX
;-----------------------------------------------------
    add eax, 30h

    ret
DigitToAscii ENDP
END main
```

Comment: Changing things like `add eax, 30h` to `add eax, '0'` would improve code readability a lot. Also, perhaps `add eax, '30'` should be `add eax, '0'`.

Comment: Thank you very good catch.  Still hanging though.

Comment: Does ReadChar return the result in EAX?  Does WriteChar preserve EAX? AsciiToDigit clearly expects the result in EAX, so check that assumption.  If your debugger isn't helping, remove lines until it works.  Remove the WriteChar.  Replace the ReadChar with a simple assignment to EAX (to pretend that you called the function and got a good input back).  Skip the call to AsciiToDigit.  Trim your program until it works.  Also, you should document "why", not "what".  Comments like "shift ebx left one" are useless because it's clear what `shl ebx, 1` does.  But *why* are you shifting ebx left by 1?

Comment: Advice: Format the code better. Break up every subtask an as small pieces (subroutines) as possible and keep every subroutine as short as possible. Group correlated subsections in modules. Don't scatter the code with unnecessary comments. Use a well established [calling convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86_calling_conventions) instead of arbitrary register haxoring.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things that I can see so far.

In the first part, when you try to get a base number, if you enter 10, the code exits. I think you need to look at each character as it is entered from the user.

Next, you are hanging because the program seems to be continuing to go through getting digits while you are reading in the integers for that particular base.  In this point of the code:

```
;-----------------------------------------------------
; AsciiToDigit PROC
;
; This procedure receives the ASCII code of a digit and returns 
; the numerical digit value.
; Receives: EAX register
; Returns:  EAX
;-----------------------------------------------------
cmp eax, 61h
jb Upper
sub eax,61h
jmp done
```

When you subtract 61h from EAX, if the person has hit "Enter", that value goes away.  Meaning 13h will be subtracted with 61h, leaving AL at ACh.  All of this means that you are never going to see a 13h for an enter as long as the code continuously subtracts 61h.

I think you might want to put in some more cmp's and really think about the code a bit more in this regard.  Also, be careful what you push and pop to the stack.  Watch the registers and see what they do as you perform those functions.

Just some things to look at and hope it helps.